# angular-mock vs. angular-mocks. What's the difference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) I read:

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.x",  <--- this
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.x"
  }
}
```

And here (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) I read:

```
First include angular-mock.js in your HTML:

    <script src="angular.js">
    <script src="angular-mock.js">  <--- this
```

1. What is "angular-mock(s)"?
2. What is correct: "angular-mock" or "angular-mocks"?
3. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that was a mistake, a proper name is `angular-mocks`, `packages.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*",
    "angular": ">=1.3.0-beta",
    "angular-resource": ">=1.3.0-beta",
    "angular-cookies": ">=1.3.0-beta",
    "angular-sanitize": ">=1.3.0-beta",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": ">=1.3.0-beta",
    "angular-scenario": ">=1.3.0-beta"
  }
}
```

And inclusion in `karma.conf.js` (in my case, you have another path):

```
'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
```

Also I can't find such package `angular-mock` in `bower`. Perhaps that was an old name.